# How to get string-value of selected cell in datagrid (VS 2008)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

How do I get the value of the currentCell of a dataGrid-Control?
I'm using VS2008 for Windows CE.

I have an 'CurrentCell'-Element.
Its .toString()-method only gets the "windows.forms.datagrid".
How do I get the value?
It's a dataGrid, not a dataGridView!

some code:

```
DataGridCell dc = test_dataGrid.CurrentCell;
string cellValue = dc...
```

I tried it with .toString after dc, but that get's only the name of the control.Other given Properties are 'rowNumber','columnNumber', 'equals', 'getHashCode' and 'getType'

Comment: have you tried a google search there are plenty of excellent working examples on the internet as well as here on `stackoverflow` also can you show what relevant code you've actually tried..?

Comment: I did, and 95% of my solutions were for dataGridViews, and the other 5% were questions like mine, with answers relating to the dataGridView. Do you think code matters for my question? I could write the name of my dataGrid. I don't think that would help anyone. Since the properties of the 'currentCell' are very less I thought there might be a helpful other idea. But I'll add basic code.

Comment: `CurrentCell.Value`?

Comment: isn't available. That would have been too easy ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DataGridCell dc = test_dataGrid.CurrentCell;
String cellValue =  test_dataGrid[dc.RowNumber, dc.ColumnNumber].ToString();
```

based on the this MSDN link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287674(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much! (I read that earlier... must have missed it ;))